# Extract gray value of every pixel and write on file using openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to use openCV for importing an image and for every pixel extract the corresponding gray value.  I decided to use openCV because it is simple but I have a problem.  When I run the program, it report these errors:

> opencv_core249 is not present on the computer.
>
> opencv_highgiu249 is not present on the computer
>
> opencv_imgproc249 is not present on the computer

I am using openCV version 2.4.9 and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  Here isthe code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat colorImage = imread("blackwhite.png");

// First convert the image to grayscale.
Mat grayImage;
cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

// Then apply thresholding to make it binary.
Mat binaryImage(grayImage.size(), grayImage.type());
threshold(grayImage, binaryImage, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

// Open the file in write mode.
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("MyFile.txt");

// Iterate through pixels.
for (int r = 0; r < binaryImage.rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < binaryImage.cols; c++)
    {
        int pixel = binaryImage.at<uchar>(r, c);

        outputFile << pixel << '\t';
    }
    outputFile << endl;
}

// Close the file.
outputFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you link opencv and vs??

Comment: The title is misleading

Comment: Yes i have link opencv and visuale studio

Comment: Have you recompiled OpenCV with vc14 compiler (VS 2015)? Have you linking dynamically (dll)? If so, have you put dlls into your executable folder, or added them to system PATH? Can you post your include and library directories, and your additional libs?